# CMake dynamically generated header dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have two static libraries : **libfoo** and **libbar**, each one being in its own directory.

**libfoo** contains a `includes/` directory which contains a single file `A.h`. It also contains a `sources/` directory which contains `B.gen`. A custom rule should create a new header `B.h` and a new source file `B.c`.

**libbar** contains a `includes/` directory which contains a single file `C.h`. It also contains a `sources/` directory which contains `C.c`. This file include the `A.h` and the `B.h` from **libfoo**.

The question is : according to these rules, how can I write the CMakeFiles.txt of the two libraries (from my understanding, the tricky part is to have all the libfoo headers in the same directories, but maybe I'm misleading) ?

File hierarchy :

```
/
  libfoo/
    includes/
      A.h
    sources/
      A.c
      B.gen
    CMakeLists.txt
  libbar/
    includes/
      C.h
    sources/
      C.c
    CMakeLists.txt
```

Comment: To add libfoo includes dir, just add `include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libfoo/includes` to `libbar/CMakeLists.txt`. Or did i misunderstood question?

Comment: I have read that the generated files should be somewhere in the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`, so I would need to do something like a copy of the directories. Since I have asked this question I have tried something which seems to work (`file(COPY ...)`) but there is still a problem about this command not checking file versions (if I edit a file in the source directory, it will not be copied if y type `make` again).

Comment: Can you show the CMake code for your generating rule?

Comment: don't forget you can invoke CMake in 'command mode' from your CMakeLists.txt file, like this: `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different ${input_file} ${output_file}`

Answer (score 3):

You should not copy any generated files to the source directory. The separation between a source directory and a build directory is intentional and called out-of-source builds to not pollute the source directory during your build with generated files.

What you need to do in this case is:

1. Define a custom command which translates your B.gen to a B.h file using add_custom_command. This will generate the B.h inside the CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR, which reflects the source directory your CMakeLists.txt is in relative to the project root CMakeLists.txt. It will look something like this:

   add_custom_command(OUTPUT B.h
                      COMMAND my-gen B.gen B.h
                      DEPENDS B.gen)
2. Add the folder where the file was generated to the include directories using the include_directories function. If all of this was done in a single CMakeLists.txt you could use include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

The CMake dependency parser will now, once it wants to build C.c, analyze its contents and find out that B.h is required for building it. With the add_custom_command you have told it how to create that header and it will invoke your generator.

You should have a look at how out of source builds work in CMake to correctly understand the folder hierarchy.

Comment: So what if this isn't all in a single CMakeLists.txt file (#2)?  How does one create the necessary include_directories() references from programs and directories scattered far from the source and binary directories where the generated header is created?

Comment: @CXJ, you can use relative paths, e.g. INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/../../other/path/in/build/tree ../../other/path/in/source/tree). Basically you can just do everything you do with the source dirs in parallel with binary dirs by starting from CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR. CMAKE_BINARY_DIR will reference the top-level build folder in case you want to use absolute paths.

Comment: Note that in order for CMake to detect the dependency, the custom command must be added before adding any targets that include the directory with the generated files.

Comment: CMake doesn't handle all dependencies correctly this way. It doesn't rebuild source files dependent on header file when it being regenerated. Don't know what's wrong - solution, or it's a bug in CMake... And @Eric amendment
doesn't help too. So be careful!

Comment: Hmm... Seems like a small bug (feature?) in CMake. It works correctly only when you done everything right just before first build with updated cmake files. I've missed important amendment of @Eric , which caused me to get into potentially very dangerous situation (because CMake just silently started to make things wrong being unnoticed) until I've managed to fix it. So, once again, be careful!

Comment: And one more important step missed: generated header file should be listed in target sources!